# PyOpenCL no device found

Tags: ubuntu, anaconda, nvidia, pyopencl

## Description of the problem

I'm trying to use pyopencl with my GPU in Anaconda. But no device is found. In Python I get the following output:

```
>>> import pyopencl as cl
>>> cl.get_platforms()
[<pyopencl.Platform 'Clover' at 0x7f3569088100>]
>>> cl.get_platforms()[0].get_devices()
[]
```

Also when I run `sudo clinfo`:

```
Number of platforms                               1
  Platform Name                                   Clover
  Platform Vendor                                 Mesa
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.1 Mesa 18.0.5
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd
  Platform Extensions function suffix             MESA

  Platform Name                                   Clover
Number of devices                                 0

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  Clover
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   Clover
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  No devices found in platform

ICD loader properties
  ICD loader Name                                 OpenCL ICD Loader
  ICD loader Vendor                               OCL Icd free software
  ICD loader Version                              2.2.8
  ICD loader Profile                              OpenCL 1.2
    NOTE:   your OpenCL library declares to support OpenCL 1.2,
        but it seems to support up to OpenCL 2.1 too.
```

## GPU specifications:

```
sudo lshw -C video

  *-display               
       description: 3D controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:134 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:df000000-df07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:125 memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

## Drivers for OCL:

I installed the last version of the nvidia-opencl-icd-410 package and copied the file mesa.icd from /etc/OpenCL/vendors to /usr/lib/anadonda3/etc/OpenCL/vendors as described [here](https://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/misc.html#using-vendor-supplied-opencl-drivers-linux).

Here is the content of the file:

```
libMesaOpenCL.so.1
```

I'm probably missing something and would be glad if somebody could help me!

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

As PyOpenCL seemes to be installed using conda another possibility to detect system-wide OpenCL ICDs shipped by e.g. Nvidia is to run:

```
conda install ocl-icd-system
```

as suggested by: https://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/misc.html

The pip version of PyOpenCl detects the ICDs in

```
/etc/OpenCL/vendors
```

directly.

Also make sure your nvidia drive is installed properly. If in doubt use the package manager to reinstall the driver and reboot the system after the installation.